# NSTableView Rounded Corners like UITableView Groups

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, calayer, nstableview, nsbezierpath

I'm attempting to create an NSTableView with rounded corners (much like iOS's `Grouped` style of table view).
However, this is proving to be exceptionally difficult.

I've tried to use `CALayers`:

```
// ...
self.wantsLayer = YES;
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
// ...
```

which works for `NSView` subclasses, but not `NSTableView` or `NSScrollView`.

I've also tried to override `drawRect:`, and use bezierPaths.

```
NSBezierPath *rectPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: self.bounds];
[rectPath appendBezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.bounds xRadius: 10 yRadius: 10];
[rectPath addClip];
[super drawRect: rectPath.bounds];
```

I've not tested this method on `NSView`s, but it does not work as-is for `NSTableView`s.

I've seen a few "duplicate" questions here on StackOverflow before, however they have not been able to provide satisfactory solutions.

[Rounded corners on NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418733/rounded-corners-on-nstableview) has 1 "correct" answer, seemingly marked so simply because the asker changed his objective. This question gave me the prompting to try `NSBezierPath`s, but as I've said, I can't seem to get that method working.

[NSTableView rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803973/nstableview-rounded-corners) suggests subclassing an NSScrollView, however that was equally unresponsive to `CALayers`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'd like to get clear-cut an answer not just for myself but for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also face the same problem of making round corner, but didnt got the answer.

Finally i did it in another way,I have make the Background of table transparent and **added the image of .png files of round corner of 4pixel**(that i want to show) just behind the table view .

In this way i have shown the table with round corner.
Hope this solution works for you.

Comment: A good suggestion. Any leads on how to do this programmatically?

Comment: I've been working on a to-be-open-source library to accomplish this easily. I'll update my question with my results. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Comment: @pcperini did you ever get a solution? I need the same thing in my Mac app